# How to forward the post file to an other server to the same script

Tags: php, curl, upload

I have the following script

```
    <?php 

$target_path = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/files/cache/";


$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}

?>
```

I like to modify it so, that the file is uploaded on server A and the script on Server A calls this script, you can see here, on server B, because I can't call this script directly.

How can this look like? 
On Server B, it's clear, I would use the top script. But I have to think about the script on server A.

I think I have to call the script on server B from server A with the function `file_get_contents(...)`

```
    <?php 

$target_path = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/files/cache/";


$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}
//Start upload to server  B
file_get_contents("http://server2.com/upload.php");

//...
//But here I have to add the post data-File
?>
```

But how to parse the Post-File using `file_get_contents()` or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get code files from another server. May be you have to change the logic and use ajax.